# ElasticSearch - slow aggregations and impact on performance of other operations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

There is an aggregation to identify duplicate records:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "myfield": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "myfield.keyword",
            "size": 250,
            "min_doc_count": 2
         }
      }
   }
}
```

However it is missing many duplicates due to the low size.  The actual cardinality is over 2 million.  If `size` is changed to the actual size or some other much larger number, all of the duplicate documents are found, but the operation takes 5X more time to complete.

If I change the `size` to a larger number, should I expect slow performance or other adverse effects on other operations while this is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `size` param is very critical in Elasticsearch aggregation performance and if you change it very big number like `10k` (limit set by Elasticsearch but you can change that by changing `search.max_buckets` but it will surely have adverse impact not only on the aggregation you are running but on all the operation running in Elasticsearch cluster.

As you are using `terms` aggregation which is of bucket aggregation, you can read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/search-aggregations-bucket.html#search-aggregations-bucket)

**Note: Reason for increasing the latency when you increase the size is that Elasticsearch has to do significant processing creating those many buckets and compute the entries for those buckets.**

[image]

Comment: Can I paginate the requests? e.g. send a request with size 250 and `from: 0` and the second with size 250 and `from: 250` and so on?  I guess this would only find duplicates that happen to be within the 250.